# Chrome ignores input maxlength even if type = text

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

For a HTML input, type="text", Chrome seems to ignore the maxlength attribute when the size is very large.

I can populate the input (maxlength=1000000, type=text) field from a database with 188906 characters, however only 57834 display in Chrome.  If you view the source, you can see all characters.

IE allows me to see all 188906 characters.

I know this is a weird use case, it involves a user pasting in stock tickers into an input field.

https://jsfiddle.net/n69p2bqn/

```
<input code>TOO LARGE TO POST
```

Update : It appears that a textarea can display all data in Chrome:

https://jsfiddle.net/4o1ch120/

```
<textarea code>TOO LARGE TO POST
```

I believe its still a Chrome bug though.

Comment: Looks like Chrome has an internal limit, yes. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44883

Comment: I am still a little hazy on what you are asking, but your fiddle doesn't make much sense. maxlength won't keep you from setting the value longer than the maxlength value, it just prevents user input past that point. What you are describing also doesn't make sense because without a maxlenth, the input should be allowed to be an unlimited length. I would say the two things are unrelated, and you are bumping up to a maximum value length by the browser. That said, showing that much data in a form field like this does not seem like good UI in the first place so maybe you need to rethink the problem

Comment: Thank you for the link to Chromes internal limit.  I suppose a better wording of the issue may be : Chrome appears to have an upper limit on an input box regardless of what maxlength is (or even if maxlength is left out).  I do realize that a textarea or other solution is better UI.